# Grails - controllers and tight coupling with backend

Tags: grails

When you generate controllers in grails, the controllers call methods on the domain layer directly - I quite don't understand this, every bit of me is telling me that this is kind of wrong because you are tightly coupling the backend with the frontend. I think this belongs to the service layer.

Since it would be pretty ugly to create an equivalent set of methods in the service layer for all the methods defined on domain objects, I created this `AbstractService` to delegate all (missing) method calls from the service layer to the domain layer:

```
abstract class AbstractService {
    def entityType

    /**
     * By default, this method takes the name of the service that extends this
     * class, removes the suffix 'Service' and tries to create the Class object
     * from the resulting name. Override at will.
     */
    protected Class getEntityType() {
        if (!entityType) {
            try {
                entityType = Class.forName(this.class.name[0..-8], false, Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader)
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException("Class ${this.class.name[0..-8]} could not be found. Please "
                                + "override AbstractService#getEntityType() for ${this.class}.")
            }
        }
        entityType
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        try {
            if (getEntityType()?.metaClass?.getStaticMetaMethod(name)) {
                getEntityType().invokeMethod(name, args)
            } else if (args?.last()?.metaClass?.getMetaMethod(name)) {
                args.last().invokeMethod(name, args.take(args.size() - 1))
            } else {
                throw new MissingMethodException(name, this.class, args)
            }
        } catch (MissingMethodException e) {
            throw new MissingMethodException(name, this.class, args)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I just extend this service e.g. like this:

```
class UserService extends AbstractService {
}
```

And my controllers then can look for example like this:

```
class UserController {
    def userService

    def create() {
        userService.save(new User(params))
    }

    def list() {
        userService.list(params)
    }

    // et cetera...
}
```

Don't you think this is better? Thanks to dependency injection, I can for example rewrite the whole business layer without the need to change the code in the controllers - which is kind of why we use dependency injection, isn't it?

Thanks for your answers, I would like to hear as much opinions as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This model is very used in Java Web applications and all. The Rails (and Grails followed it) community just tried to break the paradigm here, leaving it more simple. I mean, why would you delegate a service class to manipulate an entity, if this entity can simply do the job? If it's natural to the entity to do the job, then don't bring someone else to do it. That way, you avoid the [Anemic Model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) since your objects are not only data holders, but they also know how to operate its own business.

Having said that, there are times when you're better off using a service class to do operations on your entities. For example, if it involves different kind of entities at the same time and so on... So, when it's not "natural" (and you would have to force to make it work) for the entity itself to take care of the operation, then a service class is the way to go. [This article](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/01/10/does-my-rails-app-need-a-service-layer/) based on Rails gives some tips about the use of a service class.

And you are not tightly coupling the controller with the models (you said backend and front end, but I guess that's what you mean). The controller will eventually need to use the model, be it the entity itself or a service class (also Model) manipulating it.

Comment: Yes, that is all nice and cool, but what if you decided later on that you want to migrate from an SQL database to a noSQL database - you would have to rewrite the front-end (controllers) because you can't count on the domain classes having the methods defined by GORM. Or you may want your webapp to support both noSQL and SQL - how would you do that? Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: And that's a wrong premise. The domain classes are implementing GORM API. If you want to change from classic SQL to NoSQL, you change the GORM API implementation to appropriate NoSQL database, you don't touch the controllers. There are already several GORM API implementations available, just search the Grails plugins for your favourite NoSQL database.

Comment: I don't think it is a wrong premise. I think it is possible that you might want to rewrite the whole back-end to achieve some more scalability - you may go with EJB or you might decide to write the backend in C++ or whatever, I think this is possible and in that case - preserving the GORM api might not be possible at all.

Comment: Yeah, you might. And again, the solution would be to use a different implementation of the GORM API, one appropriate for the context. Just remember that using Service classes for this would not solve the problem, rather just add another level of indirection.

Comment: Well the benefit of service is that u can have two (or more) different implementations. 

I kinda agree with OP because I think anything else than basic GORM methods as save, find or delete should be in service - main GORM implementation provides a lot of hibernate specific functionality (as detached criteria API) which is commonly used quite often. Thus changing GORM implementation alone won't help if u use something else except the most basic GORM operations in your controller

Comment: @TiagoFarias The GORM API is, I think, very Hibernate specific and it leaks even in the controllers, so not only are the controllers tightly coupled with the GORM, but also with Hibernate. If I use service in the middle, I have much more control over the API that leaks in the controllers. But let me put it in a different perspective - what if you don't want to use the GORM api at all? You may decide that you want to use some not ORM solution - the future might present some better solutions for database access in grails, I dare to say that this is entirely possible, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The scaffolded controller code does not really represent ideal application architecture. Keep in mind that the generated scaffold code is just a starting point for generating the CRUD portions of your application.

You are correct that in general, you don't want to put most of your GORM queries in Controllers, since controllers are supposed to be for interacting with the front end. You can certainly either put the query/business logic into Services or put the queries directly into Domain classes. That's why Grails Services support declarative transaction handling.